# C# Task Parallel ForEach manage multiple instances of a class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, task-parallel-library

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChromeDriver chromeDriver = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        List<string> Urls = new List<string>() {
            "https://www.google.com",
            "https://www.facebook.com",
            "https://www.youtube.com",
            "https://www.gmail.com",
            "https://www.linkedin.com"
        };

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
        {
            PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal
        };

        //options.AddArgument("headless");
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("disable-geolocation", "start-maximized", "disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
        chromeOptions.LeaveBrowserRunning = true;


        Parallel.ForEach(Urls, url =>
        {
            chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, chromeOptions, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
            chromeDriver.Url = url;
            TestClass testClass = new TestClass(chromeDriver);
            testClass.test();

        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


}

public class TestClass
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    public TestClass(OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.driver.Url);

    }
}
```

**What the above code is producing :**

[image]

**Though I wanted to have the all different 5 urls there. but its showing the last executed website. What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring `ChromeDriver chromeDriver = null;` on line 5 creates a *single* variable scoped to the `Main` method.

The `chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(...` call on line 28 
creates a *new* instance, but assigns it to the variable previously declared in the *enclosing* scope (i.e. on line 5). Thus, every assignment in the callback overwrites the assignments of all other callback executions.

What you want to do is

- remove `ChromeDriver chromeDriver = null;`
- replace `chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver` with `var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver`, thus creating an instance scoped to the callback rather than the `Main` method.